# How to write function with two generics and enforce that one generic implements the other

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal is to receive **any two generics** and have the type checkers enforce that the second generic implements the first generic.

This C# snippet will raise a compilation time error if someone tries to call this function with a TType generic that does not implement the IType generic.

```cs
public static void Foobar<IType, TType>() where IType : TType { }
```

I'm trying to write the equivalent code in Python, where either mypy or pyright type checkers would catch this error.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=T) # Seems we cannot bind to another TypeVar
```

Sample code:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, runtime_checkable

T = TypeVar("T")

@runtime_checkable
class IBar(Protocol):
    def hello(self) -> None:
        ...

class Bar:
    def hello(self) -> None:
        return None

@runtime_checkable
class IFoo(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> None: ...

class Foo:
    def foo(self) -> None: ...


def foobar(a: type[T], b: type[T]) -> T:
    instance = b()
    assert isinstance(instance, a)
    return instance

a = foobar(IBar, Bar) # should pass
b = foobar(IBar, Foo) # should fail
c = foobar(IFoo, Foo) # should pass
d = foobar(IFoo, Bar) # should fail
```

Mypy is giving me this error, which is not the expected error:

> error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[IBar]" is expected

And Pyright is giving no error at all, but the expected error is to have it complain that Foo does not implement IBar protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bound argument of TypeVar checks that provided instance are subtype of bounded type, as mentioned in the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). It requires IBar definition before TypeVar instance declaration, as follows:

```py
@runtime_checkable
class IBar(Protocol):
    def hello(self) -> None:
        ...

T = TypeVar("T", bound=IBar)
```

Then, in the following line:

```py
b = foobar(IBar, Foo)
```

"Foo" will be highlighted with this problem (using vscode with 'type checking mode' set to strict)

```
Argument of type "Type[Foo]" cannot be assigned to parameter "b" of type "Type[T@foobar]" in function "foobar"
  Type "IBar" cannot be assigned to type "Foo"
```

#### Edit

A solution working for multiple types. The above solution only works if the protocols implements IBar. The naive solution would be to have a function for each protocol, but this reduces the interest of typing. However, it is possible to define a function which takes a protocol class and return a function that performs operation on the implementations.

```py
def foobar(a: T) -> Callable[[T], T]:
   return lambda x: x

foobar(IFoo)(Bar) # Argument 1 has incompatible type "Type[Bar]"; expected "Type[IFoo]"
foobar(IFoo)(Foo)
foobar(IBar)(Foo) # Argument 1 has incompatible type "Type[Foo]"; expected "Type[IBar]"
foobar(IBar)(Bar)
```

The type checking will show warning on the requested lines and with the requested message. However, we can not use `a: type[T]` since a will be an abstract class.

Comment: Hi, this will work only for IBar, I would like to be able to receive any two types A, B and ensure that B is a valid implementation of A

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Protocol)

class IBar(Protocol):
    def hello(self) -> None:
        ...

def foobar[T: IBar](arg: T) -> None:
    pass

class Bar:
    def hello(self) -> None:
        pass

class Foo:
    pass

foobar(Bar())  # This is valid
foobar(Foo())  # This will raise a type error because Foo does not implement IBar
```